# Optimization of a square into a circle with a radius of 4

Tags: calculus, optimization, pythagorean-triples

This is a really difficult one:
 Find the dimensions of the rectangle of maximum area that can be inscribed in a circle of radius r = 4.
I've been struggling with it for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the vertices be $(\pm a,\pm b) $

Then $a^2+b^2=4^2$.

And area is $2a*2*b$

Maximize it.

Comment: I don't understand why the area would be 2a * 2b. Isn't it a*b as in length*width?

Comment: It is if the sides are a,b.  But the sides aren't a,b.  I said the *vertices* are $(\pm a,\pm b) $ so the sides are 2a,2b.  It's arbitrary.  I could have said the sides are a,b and the vertices would be  $(\pm\frac 12 a,\pm \frac 12 b) $ and $a^2/4+b^2/4=4^2$.  You'd get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Diameter of the circle is $8$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be sides-lengths of our rectangle.
Thus, since $a^2+b^2=8^2$, we obtain:
 $$ab\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=32.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=4\sqrt2$,

which says that $32$ is a maximal value and dimensions are $4\sqrt2$ and $4\sqrt2$.

Comment: don't think its that easy

Comment: it says find the dimensions. I have no idea what you found....

Comment: @j.doe You have to work out the details yourself.

Comment: @user202729 I fixed my post. See now  please.

Comment: it can be that easy, "calculus" and "hard" arent synonyms @j.doe

Comment: It is possible to prove that equality implies optimization with AM-GM.

Comment: @Nairit Sarkar Yes, but I think it's better to see that $ab\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ it's just $(a-b)^2\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let a and b be the dimensions:

Then $A =ab = a\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}$

Set $\frac{dA}{da} = 0$ and find $a = 4\sqrt{2} = b$

Answer (score 0):

I think I will post a careful answer, and not a hint.

Let the rectangle be $ABCD$ with $AB=a,CD=b$ and the circle has center $O$ and radius $r$ such that the circle contains the whole rectangle.
The rectangle is convex, so the statement "the circle contains the whole rectangle" $\iff$ "the circle contains all 4 points of the rectangle" $\iff OA, OB,OC,OD \leq r$.

On the other hand, by the triangle inequality,
$$OA + OC \geq AC = a^2 + b^2 $$
(by Pythagoras theorem). Similar for segment BD.

Therefore, $8 = 2r \geq \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \geq \sqrt{2ab} = \sqrt{2S}$ where $S$ is the area of the rectangle.

(as $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab \geq 0$, then $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab  $ )

$$8 \geq \sqrt{2S}$$
$$64 \geq 2S$$
$$32 \geq S$$

The equality occurs $\iff a=b$ and $O$ lies on the intersection of segment $AC$ and $BD$.